# Compare value of text box value with model property mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hello this is my details view in which I have an input. On button click I want to compare if the value of textbox with txbNumber is bigger that the property Quantity of my model -> but it gives me syntax error.

```
OnlineStore.Commercial.Models.CategoryProductDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<script src="/Scripts/dist/libs/jquery.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.bigImageTitle</td>
            <td>@Model.Title</td>
            <td>@Model.ShortDescription</td>
            <td>@Model.Description</td>
            <td>@Model.Price</td>            
        </tr>        
</table>

<label>Quantity:</label>
<input type="text" id="txbNumber" />
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" />
<script>
    function validate() 
    {
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        if (regex.test($("#txbNumber").val()))
        {
            var orderquantity=$("#txbNumber").val();
            if (  @int.Parse(orderquantity) > @Model.Quantity)
            {
               /*here is the exception
            }  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mix the Razor syntax with Javascript (one is executed before the response is sent from server to client and the second is executed fully on the client side).

Instead of:

```
if (  @int.Parse(orderquantity) > @Model.Quantity)
```

You should use the global javascript parse method for conerting strings to integers:

```
if (  parseInt(orderquantity) > @Model.Quantity)
```

Comment: Who answered first? :-D

Comment: I answered first (tips: you can easily check it by looking whose answer is higher in the answers' list, assuming that both have the same amount of votes).

Comment: I see my answer higher :-/
Anyway, of course it was just a joke. It's not about who's first but about helping people :) that's why I +1 you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can't work:

```
@int.Parse(orderquantity)
```

Try this:

```
if (  parseInt($("#txbNumber").val()) > @Model.Quantity)
```

Updated with parseInt() for safety as suggested by @bejger

Update 2:
 [check this minimal Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRHRL/)

Comment: @MilkaSalkova check Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(parseInt(orderquantity) > Number(@Model.Quantity)) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Sometimes razor gets weird about putting numbers into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your concerns.  Your javascript shouldn't be in your view.  Add a reference to a javascript file with your code.  Then you should be able to compare these values w/o issue with javascript/jquery.  If need be, add code in your $(document).ready(function () {} to set the original model value on page load for comparison.